# Output of my GUI : (1, ['1'], 2, ['2'], 3, ['2']) in python but expected output is 1(1),2(2),3(2).kindly help me in achieving this

Tags: tuples

this is my output (1, ['1'], 2, ['2'], 3, ['2']) in python but i want my output as 1(1),2(2),3(2). Have tried removing commas using remove and split command  but couldn't kindly help me out.TIA

tried split,remove,replace commands.
The error popping is "tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'". kindly help me to get through this

Comment: You need to [edit] and share your code for anyone to help you.